# font resize and cache

Tags: javascript, html

I use [jfontsize'](http://www.jfontsize.com) to increase/decrease the size of my font on my website. 
Does anyone know of a way to remember the settings between the pages and when a user returns to the site?
I've been trying to create a cookie but I'm not having much luck!

Here is what I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createCookie("textsizestyle", textsize, 365) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires;
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
                c = c.substring(1, c.length);

            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
                return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }

        return null;
    }
</script>
```

would anyone mind giving me some pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: That code will result in a syntax error.

Comment: How about these: 0x3A28213A, 0x6339392C?

Comment: Thanks - anything constructive?

Comment: Sorry Dave, that was a cheap stab at a poor joke... lol

Comment: no worries! - I've never used cookies before so I just wanted an idea of the best possible solution.